# How to write a combination that defines all possible edges in a graph?

Tags: probability, combinations

Given a graph $G=(V,E)$, I would like to define a set that contains all possible edges in the graph where the edges can't be repeated. In other words, if the graph has three nodes $x,y,z$ then I want the set $S$ to be defined as having only $S=\{(x,y),(x,z),(y,z)\}$. By not repeated I mean I don't want to allow edges as $(y,x)$.

How can I express this mathematically? I believe one needs to use combinations but not sure how to define what I need.

What I tried:

$S=$$V \choose 2$

Comment: $\{\{x,y\}\mid x,y\in V\wedge x\neq y\}$. Note that $\{x,y\}=\{y,x\}$ so there is no repeating.